# Paypal API Chained Payment - Secondary Receiver does not have paypal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

I have a website that lets retailers sell goods on-line and the website takes a percentage.
This uses a paypal chained payment.
- the user of the website is the sender.
- the website is the primary receiver.
- the retailer is the secondary receiver.

The problem is if the retailer has not set up a paypal account then the payment fails.
In the paypal documentation is says a receiver is not required to have an account but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is it possible to set up a chained payment to a secondary receiver without a paypal account?

Comment: As the creator of API Chaining, I can tell you that I talked to the head of API development, Deepak Nadig about this. He had one-on-ones with me several times and the aren't doing API chaining; the best they can do is 'method chaining'. And I believe you have to have a Paypal acct regardless.

Answer (score 0):

All recipients must have a valid Paypal account.

For this specific purpose, I've created an open-source library for Rails/ActiveMerchant that will help you with checking the Verified Status of a paypal account:
https://github.com/jonaphin/active_paypal_adaptive_accounts

There are other libraries out there for different languages and frameworks that can help you achieve this.